# Intermediate display similar to PrintTemporary

Tags: front-end, dynamic, timing

Using MMA we often come across situations like the following

```
cityLIST = CityData[#, "Name"] & /@ CityData[];
```

This code if you evaluate will emit some display pane to the front end until evaluation finishes.
[image]
This is really nice functionality of MMA. Now when I want some of my time consuming code to have the same functionality I thought of `Monitor` or `PrintTemporary`. But is there a streamlined way to use this functions or anything similar (e.g some magical `` Internal`Bag ``, `` Internal`StuffBag ``) to achieve such dynamic message display that is not controlled by some artificial `Pause[n]` for some $n$ seconds? It will be best to have a general purpose code that works like the following for `Module` or `Block` constructs.

```
Module[{x,y,...<variables>}
       code snippet I;
       (* DynamicDisplayFunction must not affect the interdependent snippets I,II,..,n *)
       DynamicDisplayFunction[code snippet II];
       code snippet III;
       .
       . 
       code snippet n;
       .
       .
     ]
```

If such a function say `DynamicDisplayFunction` is viable then it should show some user defined temporary display to the front end while the MMA kernel evaluates the computationally cumbersome `code snippet II` part of the above `Module`.

While trying with monitor I ended up copying the design of the display but could not get rid of the disturbing `Pause[]`.

```
data = {{0.18, -0.13}, {0.84, -0.06}, {0.05,0.88}, {0.24, -0.63}, 
{0.67, 0.93}, {0.05, 0.88}, {0.65,0.92}, {0.01, 0.99}, {0.17, -0.04},
{0.23, -0.55}};
model[{a_, k_, w_, p_}][x_] = a Exp[-k x] Sin[w x + p];
Module[{vars = {a, k, w, p}}, 
       Monitor[FindFit[data, model[vars][x], vars, x,StepMonitor :> Pause[0.3]],
               Grid[{{"Curve fitting results will be ready shortly...."}}, 
                    Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Darker[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .1],
                    ItemStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
                    Directive[Darker[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .1], 11], None}, 
                    Background -> Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .9], 
                    Spacings -> {4.9, 2.2}]
                 ]
         ]
```

[image]

I doubt a bit if this type of question is fully correct in its own right as we know designing an observer for a certain system that does not affect the system itself, not even minutely, is very difficult. During a code evaluation making the kernel transmit some constant "Busy" message to the front end is it a simple job? I am also not sure if similar question is already addressed in the SE by some fellow members?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure `PrintTemporary` doesn't do your job

```
Module[{pTmp, etc},
 pTmp = PrintTemporary["bla"];
 Pause[3];(* do your stuff *)
 NotebookDelete[pTmp]; PrintTemporary["blo"];
 Pause[2] (*do more stuff*)
 ]
```

Your function would be something like

```
SetAttributes[DynamicDisplayFunction, HoldFirst];
DynamicDisplayFunction[code_, message_] := 
 Module[{tmp = PrintTemporary[message], res = code},
  NotebookDelete[tmp];
  res
  ]
```

And the `Pause` you had to put in, that's just because your computation was too fast, or I didn't get your point. I don't think the idea is for the real computation to get slower so that people can read your message, right?

Answer (score 8):

The progress cell that you see when you load data from the Wolfram server is a `"PrintTemporary"` cell. The following example is based on what is used by Mathematica to print these cells. You can modify and adapt this to suit your use.

```
monitorCell[i_] := CellPrint@Cell[
    BoxData[
        FrameBox[StyleBox[ToBoxes@StringForm["Progress: `1`", i],
             FontFamily -> "Verdana",
             FontSize -> 11,
             FontColor -> RGBColor[0.2, 0.4, 0.6]
        ],
        Background -> RGBColor[0.96, 0.98, 1.],
        FrameMargins -> {{24, 24}, {8, 8}},
        FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0.2, 0.4, 0.6],
        StripOnInput -> False]
    ], "PrintTemporary"
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need your evaluations to take enough time for this to display. For example this works fine for me:

```
DynamicModule[{tmp},

 Monitor[
  tmp = First @
    Import["http://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/balance/country.zip", "*"],

  Grid[{{"imported data being downloaded..."}}, Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> Darker[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .1], 
   ItemStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     Directive[Darker[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .1], 11], None}, 
   Background -> Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .9], 
   Spacings -> {4.9, 2.2}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]